# Does the Bootstrap-Validator only validate unique name-attributes?

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my webpage a form appears twice. The form is identical except for the id. The names in the form are the same. Let's say (very simplified):

```
<form id="a1">
  <input type="email" name="xy">
</form>

<form id="a2">
  <input type="email" name="xy">
</form>
```

I have added this information to the Bootstrap-validation-script, simplified:

```
$('#a1').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    fields: {
        xy: {
            validators: {
                emailAddress: {
                    message: 'Invalid mail-address'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

$('#a2').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    fields: {
        xy: {
            validators: {
                emailAddress: {
                    message: 'Invalid mail-address'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In this case the Boostrap-Validator stops working. It works when I give different names to the input-elements.

Now my question is: Does the Bootsrap-Validator only work when each element to be validated has a unique name?
If this is the case: I am forced to use always the same name (CMS generates and interprets the forms) - is there any solution for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what bootstrap validator library are you using? google returns a bunch.

Comment: This one: https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator // http://bootstrapvalidator.com

Comment: is it possible for you to set up a live example at http://bootsnipp.com/?

Comment: that's not possible, I would have to upload the whole validation-library.